# How can acceleration be maximum in a spring oscillator when velocity is zero?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, harmonic-oscillator, spring

Since acceleration is equal to $\Delta v / \Delta t$, and velocity is equal to zero. Then wouldn't acceleration also be zero? I have seen a response talking about differential equations, but how can the above basic formula be ignored?

Comment: What do you think $\Delta v$ means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since acceleration is equal to $\Delta v / \Delta t$ and velocity is equal to zero. Then wouldn't acceleration also be zero?

This is an often asked question in other topics eg an object thrown vertically upwards at it greatest height has no velocity, does that mean it will stay there for ever?

Acceleration is the rate of **change** of velocity with respect to time,  $\Delta v / \Delta t$, not  velocity divided by time, $v/t$.

Zero acceleration implies zero change in velocity which in turn means that if the velocity of a body is zero it will stay at zero for ever.

With a non zero constant value of acceleration a body in successive intervals of time might have a velocity of $. . . . +2,\,+1,\,0,\,-1,\,-2\, . . . \rm m/s$ in a particular direction.
Notice that the body is slowing down, stops and the starts moving in the opposite direction ie its velocity is still changing even when the velocity is zero.

Comment: Just to clarify, finding the acceleration would require us to imput values into Δv/Δt . Using the first two numbers you have given as example, would give us 1-2/Δt . Implying that will give us a negative velocity since time can't be negative. Using negative one and zero would give us -1-0/Δt . So initially the negative sign means the velocity is decreasing, and in the second half it means it's going in the opposite direction, right?

Comment: With the numbers I have quoted the (component of) velocity in a particular direction is decreasing by $-1$ in every time interval. So from $0$ it goes to $-1$ which is smaller than $0$ and so the (component of) velocity in a particular direction is still decreasing.  Think of an object thrown up, reaching its highest point and then coming down.

Answer (score 1):

> [ ...]but how can the above basic formula be ignored?

It can't because it's inaccurate: for SHOs velocity (and acceleration) is instantaneous and constantly changes, one moment to another.

In reality:

$$v=\dot{x}=\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t}$$

The generic form of the SHO (like a mass spring system) is:

$$x=A\cos(\omega t + \varphi)$$

Now calculate $v=\dot{x}$ and see what you get.

Acceleration in an SHO is given by:

$$a=\ddot{x}=\frac{\text{d}^2 x}{\text{d}t^2}$$